# How can I make a bubbly foam for coffee?

Tags: modeling

So I tried making a cup of coffee, the liquid still looks like tea but I'll mess around with settings to make it look like one (of course, tips would be really helpful). But I'm more concerned on how could I make foam for the top layer (white foam) look bubbly and not smooth?

[image]

Comment: Just to add - for most problems, there is [BlenderGuru video](https://youtu.be/Xbc3KMIOuKM) :).

Comment: yeah I've watched this video, but he used to explain less back then and I got lost on how he did some actions, especially when his Blender version differs from mine.

Answer (score 1):

i assume you are using Blender-Guru's doughnut tutorial.
While there are more than one way to do this, easiest would be for you to re-trace the steps that you took to create particles for the sprinkles. 
if not it could be found here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA

1. Create a single sphere bubble, assign a transparent but a little whitish material.
2. Select the Coffee mesh & Add a particle system to it: type "Hair".
3. Select the Bubble sphere as the object instead of the sprinkle as shown in the video.
4. Weight-Paint mostly around the edge where coffee meets glass on the surface.
5. Play around with random scale particle setting to get the desired effect.

Comment: Yeah this is his tutorial I'm doing. Anyways, I got the bubbles around the foam now, but how do I subtract those areas with the bubbles? It looks now like it grew fungus balls.

Comment: Can u send a screenshot?

Comment: Here - https://gyazo.com/76681eb0a1d50f0585c6d61b931398fb

Comment: There are few more steps to get a decent outcome.

Comment: 1. select only the "Faces"  in the coffee surface , in the edit mode-> create duplicate Shift+D -> re-parent with 'P' -> this will create a new surface for the bubbles particles alone. so it wont go all over the cup.

2. Try using the Boolean modifier on the Bubble/Bubble particle Surface (whichever that works)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViGTkjW997E
(reverse this tutorial for cheese)

Comment: You need to add the Cup as the subtracting object for the Boolean modifier here.

Comment: before adding the Boolean modifier. make sure you have the desired particle formation. then you have to convert the bubble particles in to single mesh. like this.
https://odederell3d.blog/2018/02/09/convert-particles-to-mesh-in-blender/

Comment: ugh, I tried your steps, but these things seem a bit complicated for me. I tried to convert those bubble particles into separate objects and then use the boolean modifier, but nothing happened. I tried inverting and just generally messing around until I started to get a bad headache while making a big mess. Thanks for the help, I'll try later when I refresh myself.

Comment: Do a small scale first big bubbles. So you can see the changes. Then move on to the actual version. Headache? Officially welcome to the world of 3d..

Comment: Lol thanks, at least I keep moving forward, and I hope I'll benefit from modelling someday. Anyways, I managed to do the foam, doesn't look good but it's decent, thanks for helping.

Comment: You will. Keep learning. So will I. 